# Reshape SAS table

Tags: sas

I am trying to convert data like these to wide:

```
variable    name      new_num    old_num

Green       Bob          5         12
Yellow      Bob          2         1
Red         Bob          7         8
Green       Bill         4         3
Yellow      Bill         2         1 
Red         Bill         6         9
```

to get:

```
variable  Bob_new_num   Bill_new_num   Bob_old_num   Bill_old_num
Green        5                4            12            3
Yellow       2                2             1            1
Red          7                6             8            9
```

Trying different things with proc transpose but keep getting errors

Answer (score 0):

Do two transposes. First, we need to stack the data:

```
proc sort data=have;
    by variable name;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=have2;
    by variable name;
    var new_num old_num;
run;
```

Which gets us this:

```
variable    name    _NAME_      COL1
Green       Bill    new_num     4
Green       Bill    old_num     3
Green       Bob     new_num     5
Green       Bob     old_num     12
Red         Bill    new_num     6
Red         Bill    old_num     9
Red         Bob     new_num     7
Red         Bob     old_num     8
...         ...     ...         ...
```

Notice how `name` and `_NAME_` could be used to create unique column names  if we combined them together. `proc transpose` lets us do exactly that with the `id` statement.

We can create an ID out of the combination of `name` and `_NAME_` such that it creates the variables `Bill_new_num`, `Bill_old_num`, etc. We'll use the `delim=_` option to add an `_` between the two values when it puts them together, otherwise it would be created as `Billnew_name`, `Billold_name`, etc.

```
proc transpose data=have2 out=want(drop=_NAME_) delim=_;
    by variable;        
    id name _NAME_;
    var COL1;
run;
```

```
variable    Bill_new_num    Bill_old_num    Bob_new_num    Bob_old_num
Green       4               3               5              12
Red         6               9               7              8
Yellow      2               1               2              1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Proc REPORT` to see the data in wide shape.

```
data have ;
input color $  name $    new_num    old_num;
datalines;
Green       Bob          5         12
Yellow      Bob          2         1
Red         Bob          7         8
Green       Bill         4         3
Yellow      Bill         2         1 
Red         Bill         6         9
;

proc report data=have;
  column color new_num,name old_num,name;
  define name / across ' ' descending;
  define color / group order=data;
run;
```

[image]